# Sitecore JSS how to get media library item directly

Tags: jss

In `Sitecore JSS`, how can we refer a media item in the front end?(image ,pdf file etc)
Can we use Layout Service? Any other way?

Comment: The Layout service can be used on items for which presentation details (components) defined. To access Media Items directly, you can use the ItemService.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this but purely based on your requirement. If you are looking for any image which is part of your web page, I would recommend you to upload the image in media library but refer the same in your page item using an Image field for ex. **sampleField**. From layout service you could able to access this image field and render in JSS app,

```
import { Image } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react';
const TestImage = (props) => (
  <Image media={props.fields.sampleField} />
);
export default TestImage;
```

Other ways are using [Item Service](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/the-itemservice.html) or [GraphQL](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/graphql-overview) where you no need to worry about your Layout Service or Page Item. You can directly access any media folder/item using Item Service or GraphQL and render wherever you want.

Also you can consider customizing the Layout Service for your need, but it's up to you to pick a right approach for your need.